# How to add a function/event listener to an element created with ES6's template literals?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tried this:

```
const el = `<button class="create-panorama" onclick="${test()}">Create panorama</button>`

function test () {
  console.log('esesesee')
}

element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', el)
// element = <div id="element"></div>
```

However, nothing happens when I click the button.

What's the best way to add a click action to `button`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"What's the best way to add a click action to button?"*

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
const el = '<button class="create-panorama">Create panorama</button>';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', el);

const cp = document.querySelector('.create-panorama');
cp.addEventListener('click', test, false);

function test() {
  console.log('esesesee')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  onclick="${test()}"
```

That basically tries to execute:

```
 ${test()}
```

which obviously won't work as you cant use template literals outside of a string. Therefore just do

```
onclick="test()"
```

> What's the best way to add a click action to button?

Inline event listeners are bad for a few reasons, always use `.addEventListener` !

```
  const el = document.createElement("button");
  el.textContent = "Click me!";
  el.className = "sth";
  el.addEventListener("click", test);

  element.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `${test()}` to just `test()`

```js
const el = `<button class="create-panorama" onclick="test()">Create panorama</button>`
document.getElementById("i");
i.innerHTML = el
function test () {
  console.log('esesesee')
}
```

```html
<div id="i"></div>
```

**Note:** The best way to add listener is `.addEventListener(..` as inline event handlers are executed as  `eval` in HTML markups - It is a bad practice, difficult to manage.